# Modification of a javascript global let variable in local scope

Tags: javascript, scope, var, let

I am trying to learn pure javascript and stumbled upon the topic of let and var keyword. Based on my understanding, let has a local scope and var has global scope even if it is declared in an inner block of code.

The problem was in the following code.

```
let glob='global'

if(true){
  var local='local'
  console.log(local)
  glob='inlocal'
  console.log(glob)
  let glob='local'
  console.log(glob)

}

console.log(local)
console.log(glob)
```

The above gives the error 'glob is not defined' at the line `glob='inlocal'`
As the glob is declared in the outer block, shouldn't it value be updated?

Also, when I commented the lines

```
let glob='local'
console.log(glob)
```

There was no error for the code. I don't understand why this effect is there.

Comment: because without the "local" `let glob`, the `outer` `glob` is referenced

Comment: but as of that line, the inner glob isn't declared yet. Then, how can it already refer. Did I miss something on how javascript code is interpreted.

Comment: yes, you did - see dupe